# positioning items in html/css

Tags: html, css, position

I'm trying to learn some basics of HTML by using jfiddle. This is what I've done.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lqn0jch3/

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <div class="logo"></div>
            <div class="menu-options">
                <p>yeeeeeep</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.container {
    background-color : #458748;
    height: 100%;
}
.sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    width: 30%;
    background-color : #000000;

}
.logo {
    background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/3/31/Britannia_Industries_Logo.svg/1280px-Britannia_Industries_Logo.svg.png");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 30%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: aqua;


}
.menu-options {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
p {
    color: #000000;
}
```

But I can't understand why my 'menu-options' class is not being positioned just below the logo and there's some separation between them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where exactly below do you want it?

Comment: Below the .logo class, with no separation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you want?

https://jsfiddle.net/Lqn0jch3/1/

i changed the css of p

```
p {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000000;
}
```

the element `<p>` becomes margins by default, so changing its display or setting `margin: 0px;` would do the job for you

Comment: Certainly that's what I wanted, but still can't understand that. Thanks mate.

Comment: awesome. Didn't know that property of <p>. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Aldridge1991 glad that i could help

Comment: I must wait 1 more minute.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your class, modify the positioning to your needs:

```
.menu-options {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position:relative;
    top:-20px;
}
```

Comment: I already know how to do that, but that's not what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default the browser adds margin to the top and bottom of the paragraph element, so to fix this you just have to change the margin to 0.

```
p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

And you normally wouldn't use a paragraph element in a menu. An Unordered list works well. `<ul> <li>`

Answer (score 0):

Separation between them is because of default margin style on element p

You can get diffrent default margin values on diffrent browsers, try using CSS Reset scripts.